# Metro XAML custom control cannot be accessed from code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Trying to use the solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490709/righttapped-not-fired-on-metro-listviewitem-if-listview-in-other-than-none-sel) question gives me a weird problem. (Replicated here for convenience)

This is a solution for an issue with `ListView` swallowing the right-click event and preventing the AppBar from opening - A class which inherits `ListView` and overrides the `OnRightTapped` event of `ListViewItem`:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new MyListViewItem();
    }
}

public class MyListViewItem : ListViewItem
{
    protected override void OnRightTapped(Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRightTapped(e);
        e.Handled = false; // Stop 'swallowing' the event
    }
}

<CustomControls:MyListView
    x:Name="ItemsList"
    ...
    SelectionMode="Single"
    RightTapped="MyListView_RightTapped">
</CustomControls:MyListView>
```

I have implemented a custom control as specified, in a new namespace called CustomControls, exactly as described. I've added that namespace to MainPage.xaml

```
xmlns:CustomControls="using:CustomControls"
```

When I then try and reference 'ItemsList' in code behind, I get a compile error

```
The name 'ItemsList' does not exist in the current context
```

I've tried building, rebuilding, cleaning the solution, closing and reopening the solution, putting the classes under the main project namespace, all to no avail.

**To summarise, MainPage.cs cannot see a Custom Control on MainPage.xaml**

UPDATE 2: Reworded the question to remove irrelevant issues. I've also changed the title to reflect the real issue.

Comment: Are you custom controls in a different project?  I have seen this when items are in projects is that they both build to different frameworks.  i.e. one .NET Client profile and the other is not.  I know this is a WinRT are you trying to use a non WinRT control?

Comment: Nope, all in the same project, and the control is a custom one based on a standard WinRT ListView.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was using `Name` but should have been using `x:Name`. Apparently custom controls and user controls need to use `x:Name` rather than `Name` to be seen in code behind.

More info on the difference here:

[In WPF, what are the differences between the x:Name and Name attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes)